# How to connect TCL to Python

Tags: python, tcl

I've created a script on python that is initiating as SSH session (between windows and Linux) and allow to execute commands .
Now I need to connect the python script with TCL . 
I need to call this script with some args using TCL , and get a response to TCL of python console .

this is my Python script :

import threading, paramiko
from paramiko import client
import time
class ssh:
    client = None
    shell = None

```
def __init__(self, address, username):
    print("Connecting to server.")
    cert = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("QA-SIP-Evgenyz.pem")
    self.client = client.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(address, username=username, pkey=cert)
    self.transport = paramiko.Transport((address, 22))
    self.transport.connect(username=username, pkey=cert)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    print("Connected")

def closeConnection(self):
    if self.client is not None:
        self.client.close()
        self.transport.close()

def openShell(self):
    self.shell = self.client.invoke_shell()

def sendShell(self, command):
    if self.shell:
        #print("trying to run command " + command)
        self.shell.send(command + "\r")
        time.sleep(0.6)
        #self.shell.send("\r")

    else:
        print("Shell not opened.")

def process(self):
    global connection
    while True:
        # Print data when available
        if self.shell is not None and self.shell.recv_ready():
            alldata = self.shell.recv(1024)
            while self.shell.recv_ready():
                alldata += self.shell.recv(1024)
            strdata = str(alldata, "utf8")
            strdata.replace('\r', '')
            print(strdata, end = "")
            if strdata.endswith("$ "):
                print("\n$ ", end = "")
  IP = 1.1.1.1

  user = ubuntu

  connection = ssh("IP", "user")

  connection.openShell()

  while True:

    #Just to test the connection

    connection.sendShell("ls -l")
```

Now I need to find a way to call this Python class via TCL with arguments. 
I am not sure how the Python class shpuld be written to be able getting the ards from elsewhere . 
And also, how the "return" works, how can I show the console ?

Comment: Do you want the code to be called as a subprocess or in the same process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tcl script, you should be able to execute the python code using the `exec` call with the arguments you want to pass. You could find more information in the following tcl [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl26.html).